# Partial Derivative of a Material Derivative Illegal Manipulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $x = f(t)$ and $\phi = f(t)$ and $r = f(t)$ and $\dot{x} = u = f(x, r,\phi,t)$
where $x$ is the particle displacement, $\phi$ is the angular rotation, $r$ is the radius, $u$ is the particle velocity, and $t$ is the time.

One of the terms in the Navier-Stokes system is
$\dfrac{\partial u }{\partial r}\bigg|_{\phi, x, t}$

If we want to convert to displacement formulation, we could replace $u$ with $\dot{x}$

$\dfrac{\partial u }{\partial r}\bigg|_{\phi, x, t} = \dfrac{\partial \dot{x} }{\partial r}\bigg|_{\phi, x, t}$

When is it legal to move the partials and how should this be handled when you take partials holding certain variables constant and you want to maintain this notation?  This is important in thermodynamics.

$ \dfrac{\partial \dot{x} }{\partial r}\bigg|_{\phi, x, t} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(\dot{x}\bigg)\bigg|_{\phi, x, t} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\bigg)\bigg|_{\phi, x, t} = \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r \partial t}\bigg|_{\phi, x, t} $

Comment: In mathematical notation we usually say what something is a function of and then just write partial derivatives without labeling the variables that were held constant. Thus for instance I might introduce $u(x,r,\phi,t)$ and write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}$; in mathematical notation this automatically holds $\phi,x,t$ constant. This is convenient with multiple partial derivatives, since you avoid exactly the difficulty that you seem to be experiencing.

Comment: This is not convenient for thermodynamics, where we like to think of the same quantity as a function of different sets of variables. Accordingly, in thermodynamics most of the *first* partial derivatives of familiar quantities with respect to familiar quantities have their own independent symbols, and we write second derivatives as first partial derivatives with those symbols. Thus for instance if I want to differentiate $E$ with respect to $V$, holding $S$ constant, and then with respect to $S$, holding $V$ constant, I can just write $-\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}$.

Comment: As for exchanging mixed partial derivatives, that's justified provided all of the first partial derivatives are continuous, which is almost always true in applications. So for instance $\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial V \partial S}=\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial S \partial V}$, which is one of the "Maxwell relations".